# wildfly 23.0.1.Final with jaegertracing exception

Tags: wildfly, jaeger

I am running on Wildfly 23.0.1.Final (openjdk 11) under Centos 8.

I am not using opentrace in my application at all and i also did not add any jaeger dependency.
Whenever i look in the logs, i often get an excpetion(Level: Warn) the looks like the following:

```
> 021-04-28 15:08:29,875 WARN  [io. .internal.reporters.RemoteReporter]
> (jaeger.RemoteReporter-QueueProcessor) FlushCommand execution failed!
> Repeated errors of this command will not be logged.:
> io.jaegertracing.internal.exceptions.SenderException: Failed to flush
> spans.    at
> io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.senders.ThriftSender.flush(ThriftSender.java:115)
>   at
> io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.internal.reporters.RemoteReporter$FlushCommand.execute(RemoteReporter.java:160)
>   at
> io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.internal.reporters.RemoteReporter$QueueProcessor.run(RemoteReporter.java:182)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> io.jaegertracing.internal.exceptions.SenderException: Could not send 1
> spans     at
> io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.senders.UdpSender.send(UdpSender.java:85)
>   at
> io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.senders.ThriftSender.flush(ThriftSender.java:113)
>   ... 3 more Caused by:
> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Cannot flush closed
> transport     at
> io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.reporters.protocols.ThriftUdpTransport.flush(ThriftUdpTransport.java:148)
>   at
> org.apache.thrift@0.13.0//org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:73)   at
> org.apache.thrift@0.13.0//org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBaseOneway(TServiceClient.java:66)
>   at
> io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.agent.thrift.Agent$Client.send_emitBatch(Agent.java:70)
>   at
> io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.agent.thrift.Agent$Client.emitBatch(Agent.java:63)
>   at
> io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.senders.UdpSender.send(UdpSender.java:83)
>   ... 4 more Caused by: java.net.PortUnreachableException: ICMP Port
> Unreachable   at java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:695)   at
> io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.reporters.protocols.ThriftUdpTransport.flush(ThriftUdpTransport.java:146)
>   ... 9 more
```

These messages fill the logfiles and i do not know how to disable the unwanted opentrace feature.
I was not able to find something on google concerning this strange exception.
Does anybody has some idea?

best regards

shane

Comment: If you don't use it, you can do something like the following in the CLI:
/subsystem=microprofile-opentracing-smallrye/jaeger-tracer=jaeger:write-attribute(name=sampler-param, value=0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't use it, you can do something like the following in the CLI:

```
/subsystem=microprofile-opentracing-smallrye/jaeger-tracer=jaeger:write-attribute(name=sampler-param, value=0)
```

Another solution is to remove the opentracing subsystem, install jaeger or wait for a release of WildFly with a fix for https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-14625

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this by remove

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-opentracing-smallrye:3.0" default-tracer="jaeger">
    <jaeger-tracer name="jaeger">
        <sampler-configuration sampler-type="const" sampler-param="1.0"/>
    </jaeger-tracer>
</subsystem>
```

in standalone.xml

Answer (score -1):

In parallel to wildfly, execute the jaeger application - a log tracer, with a suitable port configuration. You may find a docker image to run.